# views_query_alter change to operator OR for contextual filters and normal filters

Tags: views, database

My question is rather simple and I have searched quite a bit for the answer with no result.
My view produces below SQL (simplified):

```
SELECT stuff
FROM 
tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
LEFT JOIN tableC ON stuff
WHERE (( (MY_CONTEXTUAL_FILTER = '5' ) )AND(( (MY_NORMAL_FILTER IS NULL ) )))
```

All I want to do is to change that AND between the contextual filter and normal filter. I have tried to change all ANDs (including `set_group_operator()`) to OR and it does not change my AND.

Also need to mention it is an 'Entity Reference' display which I am trying to achieve the above on. Views version 7.x-3.7.

**UPDATE**

In order to achieve the above, I also tried `hook_views_pre_execute()` as below:

```
 $old_query = (string)$view->query->query();
 $new_query = str_replace('AND', 'OR', $old_query);
 $view->build_info['query']=$new_query;
```

But that doesn't work and throws and error. I know they are different approaches with different issues but both are trying to solve one problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple try to help, did you implement `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)` as following ?

First, call *Views API* in `YOUR_MODULE.module` :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_views_api() { 
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME'),
  );
}
```

Create a file `YOUR_MODULE.views.inc`. It seems that with Views, you don't need to put `files[] = YOUR_MODULE.views.inc` in your module's .info file, as you usually would.

Then implement [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) in `views.inc`.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {

    dpm($query);
    //at this point find the right part to alter and adapt following line
    $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';

  }
}
```

**EDIT:** If for any reason, you can't override the View with `hook_views_query_alter()`, [Views Filter Harmonizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer) might fit your need.

> Views Filter Harmonizer solves an operational foible with the Views
>   module regarding filtering. This small module allows you to have a contextual filter argument apply only when there is no corresponding regular (exposed) filter value present.

Last, **check also [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472) sandbox**, or test [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/357082#comment-6845160). Both rely on the same logic, setting a "*Global: Null*" contextual filters and using it in regular filters. Many people report using it to solve the same *And/Or* contextual filters issue. Good luck !

Comment: The second part `YOUR_MODULE_views_query_alter` is how I have it but I don't understand why I need the `YOUR_MODULE_views_api` as I am using Drupal 7.x and Views 3.7 ?

Comment: With `hook_views_query_alter` INTO `.module` and no `hook_views_api()` at all it works. With `hook_views_query_alter` INTO `YOUR_MODULE.views.inc` and no `hook_views_api()` at all it doesn't work. I believe the cleanest way to do that seems to put views things into `YOUR_MODULE.views.inc` for the sake of clarity, except if you have very little views stuff.

Comment: I don't believe Zoheir can change that from the GUI since the "Filters" and "Contextual Filters" are not in the same section. Last time I checked only the "Filters" have the OR/AND and Grouping ability.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the module [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472). It is a sandbox module so you will have to use git.

In your view, remove your contextual filter and replace it with a global null contextual filter.

[image]

Then add the filter that you want as the contextual filter to the normal filter area in views, and in its value argument set the value as %1 (ie you are ferencing the global null  contextual filter).

[image]

Now rearrange the filter and-or groups to your liking.

[image]

Comment: @J.Reynolds This answer did get posted about 8.5 hrs after the edit to the first answers.  However, I would say that these are different enough to warrant being standalone.  Your answer includes details about how to use the sandbox module, the other just mentions it.